# How to get disassembly after syscall in Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, kernel, visual-studio-debugging, debug-symbols

I want to get assembler sources for `NtDelayExecution()`, to understand what is `Sleep()` and how it works internally.
But only what i get in Visual Studio 2017 debugger is this:

```
NtDelayExecution:
    mov         r10,rcx  
    mov         eax,34h  
    test        byte ptr [........],1  
    jne         NtDelayExecution+15h 
    syscall  
    ret 
NtDelayExecution+15h:
    int         2Eh  
    ret
```

And it passes through `syscall` instruction like it is regular `mov` and not a `call` (even if i press F11). And result just "magically" appears, with no visible code that providing it, and no ways to find some trace or hint where it is. Seems that it works like `int 21h` interrupt in old DOS operating system times. And what it puts in eax is a function number.

What is the simpliest way to get disassembly of what is going on further?
Maybe some literature to read on the topic?
(My OS is Windows 10 x64, and IDE is Visual Studio 2017 Community)

Comment: `syscall` enter to kernel mode. to trace into - you need kernel mode debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, if there is actually need for kernel debugging session itself. If you need only disassembly and are not experienced with kernel debugging, you may go simplier way.

Mark Russinovich's [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) is a simple-to-use tool, could help to get a clue and investigate on what is happening. For example, it could display the thread call stack, and exposes kernel part of stack as well, with human-readible names:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x3f26
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x109c
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xb3f
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x377
ntoskrnl.exe!KeUnstackDetachProcess+0x2230
ntoskrnl.exe!ObDereferenceObjectDeferDelete+0x28a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0x1283
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xb3f
ntoskrnl.exe!KeDelayExecutionThread+0x106
ntoskrnl.exe!CcUnpinData+0xfe
ntoskrnl.exe!setjmpex+0x3aa3
ntdll.dll!NtDelayExecution+0x14
test.exe!main+0x1f
test.exe!__scrt_common_main_seh+0x11d
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Next step could be just disassembling `ntoskrnl.exe` with some disassembler, like [x64dbg](https://x64dbg.com/), or [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) and you would get requested disassembly, proceeding to investigate it from `KeDelayExecutionThread()` entry.

As for literature i can advice you Mark Russinovich's book, [Windows Internals](http://materias.fi.uba.ar/7508/Windows/Windows%20Internals%20Part%201%20(6th%20Edition).pdf).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The routine is performing a system call.

```
mov eax, 34h
```

The above part is putting the system call index (aka. identifier) into the EAX register which is what the Windows Kernel will later rely on for a lookup with its internal table of System Service Routines. In other words, this is what will let the Windows Kernel know that the system call is for NtDelayExecution.

```
syscall
```

The above part is actually getting the system call to happen, which is a transition from user-mode to kernel-mode. The SYSCALL instruction is part of the x86 instruction set.

The Windows Kernel will then get the address to NtDelayExecution which will be present under NTOSKRNL (kernel-mode memory), call it, and the return status is handed back down to the user-mode version of NtDelayExecution which is exported by NTDLL (which does nothing but the system call to get the kernel to perform the operation).

In layman's terms, you cannot find out the information you are looking for in user-mode; NtDelayExecution (NTDLL) signals the kernel via a system call so the kernel carries out the operation. You'll need to study kernel-mode debugging or do static reverse-engineering on NTOSKRNL.

If you can study a bit on kernel-mode debugging, set a break-point on NtDelayExecution (NTOSKRNL) to step through it when it becomes invoked by either a user-mode caller (through a system call) or a kernel-mode caller (which won't require a system call - since in this case, the caller would already be in kernel-mode).